# add test to splint method

Tags: c#, .net, csla

I am new to `c#` programming. Could someone please help me find out how to add a second test to this code :

```
if (item.CalcInsor_Desc != null)
   {
        string[] CalcInsor_Desc = item.CalcInsor_Desc.ToString().Split('.');
        schema2.CalcInsonorisation_TypeCode = CalcInsor_Desc[0];
        schema2.CalcInsonorisation_Desc = CalcInsor_Desc[1];
   }
```

It ruturn an exception "***System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.*** "in the case CalcInsonorisation_Desc is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if (item.CalcInsor_Desc != null)
{
    string[] CalcInsor_Desc = item.CalcInsor_Desc.ToString().Split('.');
        if (CalcInsor_Desc.Length >= 2)
        {
             schema2.CalcInsonorisation_TypeCode = CalcInsor_Desc[0];
             schema2.CalcInsonorisation_Desc = CalcInsor_Desc[1];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the array contains minimum required elements

```
if(CalcInsor_Desc.Length>1)
{
 schema2.CalcInsonorisation_TypeCode = CalcInsor_Desc[0];
 schema2.CalcInsonorisation_Desc = CalcInsor_Desc[1];
}
```

Or

```
  if(CalcInsor_Desc.Length=1)
    {
     schema2.CalcInsonorisation_TypeCode = CalcInsor_Desc[0];
     schema2.CalcInsonorisation_Desc = string.Empty;
    }
  if(CalcInsor_Desc.Length>1)
    {
     schema2.CalcInsonorisation_TypeCode = CalcInsor_Desc[0];
     schema2.CalcInsonorisation_Desc = CalcInsor_Desc[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!item.CalcInsor_Desc.Equals(null))
   {
        string[] CalcInsor_Desc = item.CalcInsor_Desc.ToString().Split('.');
        if(CalcInsor_Desc.Length >= 2){
            schema2.CalcInsonorisation_TypeCode = CalcInsor_Desc[0];
            schema2.CalcInsonorisation_Desc = CalcInsor_Desc[1];
        }
   }
```